# CustomListViewAdapter Layout automatically adjust to multiline if the elements would go out of screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am building an Android Application and I am displaying information in a CustomListView. I already have the whole thing working, from the ListView layout and adapter, as well as the custom objects needed.

My customListView layout file has 6 textViews inside as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/id3"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/id4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/id5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/id6"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2pt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, what happens is if one of those fields have lengthy input, say for example ids3-4, the textViews id5 and id6 tends to be "cut off" because they are out of screen bounds already.

I want to be change the layout in such a way that whenever any textViews goes out of the screen, they just go to the next line.

How can I do this?

Comment: I remember seeing [something](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) for this awhile back.

Comment: @karaokyo thank you for the lead. I will check on it.

Comment: @karaokyo Android Studio seems to have an issue when I add `compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.9@aar'` in my gradle dependencies

Comment: I think it was just updated recently. `'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.8'` is under mavenCentral

Comment: @karaokyo already did and I checked it. It works. Put your first comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Hmm.. Ok. I don't feel to good about just linking someone else's work tho. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ApmeM's [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) does exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using wrap_content so one element can expand pushing out the next. You just need to have the length fixed.

Comment: but the issue with that is if a textField would have contents longer than the fixed length, only that textField would go into multiple lines. It is a viable solution, however, I am looking for a single row with multiple lines.

Comment: I must say I'm unable to clearly grasp the intention. I suppose if you demand a sense of uniformity then you can add gravity=center which will balance a single line text vertically (and horizontally) among adjacent multi-line texts ?

Answer (score 0):

You should give a length instead of `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, then when the text is so long, you can use below codes to put '...' end of the text.

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: I don't want to ellipsize the content. they should all be visible